# Write Zend Action in a separate file and include

Tags: php, zend-framework

I need to know whether there is a way to write each Zend_Action in a separate file and include in the Zend_Controller.

(this is because I'm getting SVN conflicts always because me and my team are working in the same controller and tries to commit.)

Comment: Do you mean "each action method"? SVN conflicts are there for a reason. If you're all working on separate methods, it sounds like you have other problems (coding standard / consistency)

Comment: Whats the one good reason behind it...

Comment: This might be the sign of a bad design, remember "fat model & small controller"

Comment: We have several Actions in one Controller, developed by several developers at the same time. SVN seems to give conflicts even it messes up the line numbers comparing to previous version.

Comment: This is more of an SVN-practice issue than a Zend issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you shouldn't be having conflict *problems*. Conflicts should only occur when the same part of a file is edited differently by different authors. This is a *good thing* otherwise, how would you know which version to use?

To directly answer your question, the only approach would be to make your includes inside the action method bodies, eg

```
class MyController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function someAction()
    {
        require 'path/to/some-action.php';
    }

    public function anotherAction()
    {
        require 'path/to/another-action.php';
    }

    // etc
```

I would not advise this approach. Instead, sort out why you're having conflict issues.